# rust define function that invokes async closure?

Tags: kotlin, rust, async-await

Lets assume we have some repetitive async code that does htttp calls,
and now we want to write a function that will take that same code as closure and record everything before the request and after the request.

Here is the simplified code that i want to achieve in `kotlin` (rust experts just look below the rust code ignore kotlin example)

```
suspend fun <A, B> logRequest(req: A, callable: suspend (A) -> B): B {
   println("write down the request $req")
   val rep: B = callable(req)
   println("write down the response $rep")
   return rep
}
```

this is a smiple function that accepts a request of type `A` and a closure that will take that same `A` do some async logic and return some `B`... note that closure is suspendable (async)

and this would be used like this

```
   val request = "REQUEST"
   val response = logRequest(request) {
      println("my closure uses '$it' and can do some async stuff")
      delay(1.second) // that is async
      "RESPONSE"
   }
```

if you run that you'll get output

```
write down the request REQUEST
my closure uses 'REQUEST' and can do some async stuff
write down the response RESPONSE
```

now trying to do the exact same thing with rust (i'm new)

```
use std::fmt::Display;

// ignore this
async fn delay(millis: i64) {}

fn log_request<A: Display, B: Display>(req: A, callable: impl FnOnce(A) -> B) -> B {
    println!("write down the request {}", &req);
    let rep: B = callable(req);
    println!("write down the response {}", &rep);
    rep
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let request = "REQUEST";

    let callable = |it: &str| -> &str {
        println!("my closure uses '{}' and can do some async stuff", it);
        // delay(1000).await; // uncommenting this
        "RESPONSE"
    };

    let response = log_request(request, callable);
}
```

**what is the correct way to do this in rust?**

if you uncomment the delay invocation compiler will say `|it: &str| -> &str { is not async`
so how do you define it as async...
since i'm already running in async scope i should surely be able to invoke async closures (which are equivalent to suspendable functions in kotlin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between the Kotlin and Rust example is that your Kotlin `log_request` is `suspend` which I assume is the same as an `async` fn in Rust. You can get what you want by making `log_request` in Rust `async`, too. This requires some additional step to await the `Future` in `log_request` and some tweaks to the function definition.

After adding the `async` on `log_request`, you need to change the output of your closure to something that returns a `Future<Output=C>` where `C: Display`. Then you need to `await` the output of the closure to actually get the displayable value.

The other change is within the closure definition itself, since the closure is not `async`, you need to work around this by returning a `Future` from it. Using an `async {}` block is the solution here.

These steps invalidate some of your type ascriptions, e.g. the `&str` ascriptions on the closures can be erased entirely and if you want to keep the `rep: B` annotation, that needs to be changed to `rep: C`.

```
use std::fmt::Display;
use std::future::Future;

// ignore this
async fn delay(millis: i64) {}

async fn log_request<A: Display, B, C: Display>(req: A, callable: impl FnOnce(A) -> B) -> C
where
    B: Future<Output = C>,
{
    println!("write down the request {}", &req);
    let rep: C = callable(req).await;
    println!("write down the response {}", &rep);
    rep
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let request = "REQUEST";

    let callable = |it| {
        async move {
            println!("my closure uses '{}' and can do some async stuff", it);
            delay(1000).await; // uncommenting this
            "RESPONSE"
        }
    };

    let response = log_request(request, callable).await;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e02aaf758f1f92bd31570091e72e7b66)

Comment: If your closure does async stuff, it doesn't return `&str` anymore but rather a `Future<Output=&str>`. Thus, the type annotation is incorrect. In my answer, the type ascription is gone, and an additional `C` type is added to `log_request` which is bound to the output of the Future.

Comment: I'll add some more context to my answer since it apparently didn't provide all necessary information :)